# jQuery can change the text of input submit type but button is no longer clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am using jaquery and jquery mobile version 1.8 and I have a button like so:

```
   <div class="ui-bar-a" id="myButton" style="bottom:0;position: fixed;width: 100%">
        <input type="submit" name="Next" id="NextButton" value="Save"  /> 
   </div>
```

And I have a javascript that can change the text for it like so:

```
     $('#AnyButton').live('click', function() {             
        if(true)
        {
            $('#myButton div').text('Saving')
        }
        else
            $('#myButton div').text('Continue');
    });
```

I tried so many other ways that didn't work but this works however after I change the text the button seems to replace the myButton div content with the text Saving or Continue and thus the button is no longer clickable.

In my browser debugger the button shows a text Save appear between myButton and the Nextbutton input.

Like so:

```
<div class="ui-bar-a" id="myButton" style="bottom:0;position: fixed;width: 100%">
"Save"
      <input type="submit" name="Next" id="NextButton" value="Save"  /> 
</div>
```

Comment: "seems to replace the myButton div content"  `$('#myButton div').text('Saving')`  , well yeah you instructed it to do so. If you want to change the value of the input then you should target the input `$('#NextButton').val('Saving')`.

Comment: @Uroš I tried that first thing and it didn't work for me. I actually tried many ways with props etc .. none replaced the text except this way.

Comment: are you interested only to change the string **"Save"** in the div?

Comment: @gaetanoM not really but nothing else seem to be working so How is that possible?

Comment: `.live(` has been removed use `.on('click', function` AND a newer version as 1.8 has security vulnerabilities and newer will be faster

Comment: Your code does NOT match with your HTML markup.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper There is more going on in your code than you have presented to us and the code provided in both answers work. Here is a `jsfiddle` which shows that it works: (https://jsfiddle.net/fL047c6r/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there is more to your code than you have presented. With jQuery Mobile, each `input` is read as a Button. So you mnay need to refresh it after a dynamic update.

This code is working:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#NextButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val("Saving").button("refresh");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-bar-a" id="myButton" style="bottom:0;position: fixed;width: 100%">
  <input type="submit" name="Next" id="NextButton" value="Save" />
</div>
```

See More: https://api.jquerymobile.com/button/ and https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/button/

Comment: I am not using that version of JQuery and it is not using this click button event. it is a different event that needs to trigger it. I am using 1.8 as in the question.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper please update your post with a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your OP does not specify that you are using jQuery 1.8

Comment: @RyanWilson am not seeing an error in FireFox. Please clarify.

Comment: @RyanWilson fixed. the Snippet was using HTTP and Chrome is sensitive to non-secure links. Switched to HTTPS and it should work for you now in the Snippet.

Comment: Refresh did it : ) .button("refresh");

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your post correctly, you want to change the text of the
input, you need to change it's value property.
I think `.live` is relatively old and deprecated and should be replaced with `.on` and a delegated event handler

```
$('#AnyButton').live('click', function() {             
    if(true)
        $('#myButton').find('input[type="submit"]').val('Saving');
    else
        $('#myButton').find('input[type="submit"]').val('Continue');
});
```

Comment: this does change the value just like '$('#NextButton').val('Saving')'. however, the problem is the text on the button does not change. I checked the value of the input using an alert that shows correctly the text again on button does not update.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper Do you have multiple buttons in your `Html` with the same `id`? Is your button a part of a form, and causing a postback on click? We really need more information as to what you are currently doing in your code and your `Html`. Specifically, what is `#AnyButton`?

Comment: It is part of a form post back. anybutton is just any random button, it does trigger the action.

Comment: If you know in the form post anything else is happening then that maybe the answer otherwise this way also works: https://jsfiddle.net/q8xwLjuy/

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper If your button click is causing a postback, it will stop your javascript code from executing.